# How to tap the element next to a text in Android using Appium and Java?

Tags: java, android, automation, appium

I need to tap on the option button which is next to a given title. I have used the below xpath for that.

```
//*[@text='Copy Source Deck']/following::android.widget.ImageButton[@content-desc='deck options']
```

But it is not working. Please help me to solve this.

This is the Appium session.

[image]

Thank You.

Comment: Expecting the experts advises on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution to this issue. The correct xpath should be,

```
//android.widget.TextView[@text='deckName']/preceding-sibling::android.widget.ImageButton
```